# Returning data by reference in MATLAB from .NET object

Tags: .net, matlab, pass-by-reference

I have a .NET assembly that provides function which returns string data by reference:

```
int obj.Get_Available_SN_List(ByRef String SN_List)
```

How do I get this data into MATLAB? Seems to be a trivial question but surprisingly I do not find any information about it.

I tried things like

```
data = System.String('');
ret = netObj.Get_Available_SN_List(data);
```

but `ret` is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
[ret data] = netObj.Get_Available_SN_List(data);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.